# Iam getting a error while rendering a component in the main component using react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, web, react-component

The error is:
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {code, message, a}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

I will show my code where Iam trying to render the component:

```
document.querySelector(".App").innerHTML = "";
const errorElement = <ShowErr message={err} />;
ReactDOM.render(errorElement, document.querySelector(".App"));
```

My component:

```
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

const reload = () => {
  window.reload();
};

const ShowErr = (props) => {
  const imgStyle = {
    display: "block",
    margin: "auto",
    marginTop: "100px",
    marginBottom: "50px",
    borderRadius: "50%",
  };
  const msgStyle = {
    textAlign: "center",
    marginTop: "30px",
    fontFamily: "Ubuntu",
    color: "red",
  };
  const btnStyle = {
    display: "block",
    margin: "auto",
    marginTop: "50px",
  };

  return (
    <div className="err">
      <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
      <link
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu:wght@300&display=swap"
        rel="stylesheet"
      ></link>

      <img
        src="https://img.icons8.com/emoji/48/000000/cross-mark-button-emoji.png"
        style={imgStyle}
      />
      <h3 className="error-msg" style={msgStyle}>
        {props.message}
      </h3>
      <Button color="secondary" style={btnStyle} onClick={reload}>
        Reload and Try Again
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ShowErr;
```

Please tell if any solution

Answer (score 0):

Don't put the link elements into react component,  elements should be under the header tag which is outside of react render. Remember What you code inside react render is not HTML it is JSX.

In your HTML file

```
<head>
 <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
      <link
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu:wght@300&display=swap"
        rel="stylesheet"
      ></link>
<head>
```

Component

```
  <img
    src="https://img.icons8.com/emoji/48/000000/cross-mark-button-emoji.png"
    style={imgStyle}
  />
  <h3 className="error-msg" style={msgStyle}>
    {props.message}
  </h3>
  <Button color="secondary" style={btnStyle} onClick={reload}>
    Reload and Try Again
  </Button>
</div>
```

Mark it as answer if this solves your probelm

Answer (score 0):

As @Sarva said you can't use the link tag like this, but that will not give this specific error.
problem is with

```
{props.message}
```

it should be of a string type, it must be an object in your case so please check that.

Comment: I will try passing err.message btw it's The error catched while doing a operation

Comment: this error comes when you try to render something which is not a string or JSX as simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is an issue with prop you send to ShowErr component.

You either need to send text only into props.message

```
// assume err={code:1, message:"Err", a:true};
const errorElement = <ShowErr message={err.message} />;
```

or send whole object into props

```
// assume err={code:1, message:"Err", a:true};
const errorElement = <ShowErr {...err} />;
```

Comment: It is the error which I catched using .catch(err)

Comment: According to your error message error object has keys {code, message, a}. The first line was used to show an example of that error object (updated answer). You can just ignore the first line and use the second one if it helps you